# WeakKeyDictionary with tuple of objects as key

Tags: python, weak-references, weakhashmap

I want to use a `WeakKeyDictionary` where the keys are tuples of other objects, e.g. of type `Tuple[A,B]`, in such a way:

```py
# a,b,c defined somewhere
d = WeakKeyDictionary()
d[(a, b)] = c
```

This does not work because: `TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'tuple' object`. But even if it could create a weak ref to a tuple, you have the other problem: The tuple object here (`(a,b)`) is not referenced anymore, i.e. after this code, the dict `d` is empty again.

In principle however, having such a weak key dict to tuples should be possible. I think the behavior should be non-ambiguous and straight-forward: Whenever any part of the key gets deleted (`a` or `b`), the whole key gets removed.

How can I get this? Any easy way using the existing builtins? Or do I need to implement my own? Or is there some other library providing this?

Comment: "Whenever any part of the key gets deleted" cannot possibly happen with a tuple key, because *the tuple itself* is maintaining a reference to the parts of the key.

Comment: @jasonharper If there is a ref to the tuple to keep the tuple alive, that's then all fine. Usually the tuple is only temporary and then would get deleted, so all is fine as well. So there should not be any problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to "implement your own" in this case - and the problem is that you will need an auxiliar dictionary with stand-alone keys - so that when the time comes to del one the paired keys, you are able to find them back.

The implementation of WeakrefDicts themselves are pretty simple and straightforward, using collection.abc helpers for mappings - you could even pick the code from there and evolve it- but I think a minimal one can be done from scratch like bellow.

To be clear: this is a fresh implementation of weak-key dicts, doing exactly what you asked in the question: the keys should e any sequence of weak-referenceable objects, and when any object from the sequence is destroyed, the item is cleared in the dictionary.  This is done using the callback mechanism of low-level `weakref.ref` objects.

```
import weakref
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


class MultiWeakKeyDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.data = {}
        self.helpers = {}
        
        self.update(**kw)
    
    def _remove(self, wref):
        for data_key in self.helpers.pop(wref, ()):
            try:
                del self.data[data_key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
    
    def _build_key(self, keys):
        return tuple(weakref.ref(item, self._remove) for item in keys)
    
    def __setitem__(self, keys, value):
        weakrefs = self._build_key(keys)
        for item in weakrefs:
            self.helpers.setdefault(item, set()).add(weakrefs)
        self.data[weakrefs] = value
        
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        return self.data[self._build_key(keys)]
    
    def __delitem__(self, keys):
        del self.data[self._build_key(keys)]
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.data:
            yield tuple(item() for item in key)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({', '.join('{!r}:{!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.items())})"
```

And working:

```
In [142]: class A:
     ...:     def __repr__(s): return "A obj"
     ...: 

In [143]: a, b, c = [A() for _ in (1,2,3)]

In [144]: d = MultiWeakKeyDict()

In [145]: d[a,b] = 1

In [146]: d[b,c] = 2

In [147]: d
Out[147]: MultiWeakKeyDict((A obj, A obj):1.(A obj, A obj):2)

In [148]: len(d)
Out[148]: 2

In [149]: del b

In [150]: len(d)
Out[150]: 0

In [151]: d
Out[151]: MultiWeakKeyDict()
```

Comment: Note, iteration is unsafe in this implementation, because the weakref mechanism could remove elements from `self.data` during iteration. The stdlib `WeakKeyDictionary` sets up a [guard mechanism](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/weakref.py#L469) during iteration to delay automatic element removal, which helps, but has thread-safety problems (despite the source comment in `_IterationGuard` claiming the mechanism is thread-safe).